# Mongoose seems to block node.js application on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, raspberry-pi

I have a Mongoose find-command that takes about 4 seconds to complete (application is running on a Raspberry Pi). Furthermore I need to save data to the database every 100ms and emit an event.

The event emission and saving runs fine until the find-command is executed. Then it stops completely (both event emission and saving) until the find-command is done. I tried outputting some text right before the find-command, inside the callback and when the data needs to be saved and emitted. Nothing was output between the call to the find-command it's callback function.

As far as I understand, it should be possible for node.js to do other stuff until the callback function is called. Does it matter that the application is running on a Raspberry Pi? I haven't read about anyone else having problems with MongoDB and Raspberry Pi...
What else could be the problem?

The code where data is emitted and saved:

```
// New data received from socket connection
socket.on('new-data', function(data){

  console.log('New data'); // Never output between 'Starting find-command' and 'Completed find-command'

  someEvent.emit('new-data');

  var data = new Data({
    value1: 1234,
    value2: 5678
  });

  data.save(function(err){
    if(err) return handleErrror(err);
  });

});
```

The find-command code:

```
console.log('Starting find-command');
Data.find({value1: { $gt: min, $lt: max }}, function(err, data){
  console.log('Completed find-command');
  // Do something with data
});
```

**Update**

I tried using lean and limit in the find-command and it increased the performance significantly (from 4s to 500ms). Unfortunately that's still not good enough...

```
Data.find({value1: { $gt: min, $lt: max }}).limit(500).lean().exec(function(err, data){
  console.log('Completed find-command');
  // Do something with data
});
```

Comment: Mongoose should be able to handle multiple commands concurrently. Given the platform you're running it on (is MongoDB also running on your RaspPi?), it may be a resource starvation issue. Are you using indexes to speed up the query?

Comment: Yes, MongoDB is running on RPI. I don't think I'm using indexes. I updated the question to include the code for the find-query.

Comment: _If_ the query is causing a starvation issue, using indexes may solve your problems.

Comment: I tried to add _index: true_ to _value1_ in the schema, but it didn't change anything. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Probably not, but just to be sure you can run `db.COLLECTIONNAME.getIndexes()` from the Mongo shell to see if the index was properly created. I wonder if the platform isn't just too underpowered, or that locking may be causing the problem. See [this document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/).

Comment: I think you're right. Raspberry Pi is just not fast enough to run MongoDB with large data and frequent inserts... Thanks for your help :)